Laravel and PHP8.3 can't connect to Postgres database
I've spent quite some time on an issue with my Laravel app when upgrading to PHP8.3 and using a Postgre database, so I'm writing this to share my findings as I was not able to easliy find the answer online.
The issue was that since migrating to a new server and upgrading PHP to 8.3 in the process, my app refused to connect to my postgre database located on another server.
The error I kept getting was:

SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not send startup packet: Resource temporarily unavailable

This lead me to believe that there is something wrong with the firewall or credentials, however everything was correct.

The issue ended up being the Swoole extension (php8.3-swoole).
Removing this extension fixed the issue - for some reason they removed postgre support from what I understand.
I won't post specifics on how to remove it, I suggest you use ChatGPT and find instructions for your specific platform - I was able to do so even though I'm no expert on Linux.

Add more specifics so your answer could be complete and useful to others, like what version of swoole has issues with PostgreSQL and how to disable/downgrade/remove.
